# Spring Data not committing to DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm wondering what the best practice is to translate from DTO to DataBase through Spring Data ?

Here is what I've tried so far :

```
    @Transactional
    public void saveTemplatesFromDTOList(List<TemplateDTO> templateDTOList) {

        for (TemplateDTO templateDTO : templateDTOList) {

            em.merge(templateDTO);

        }
    }
```

However, this doesn't work. Any other way I've tried with Spring Data repository save method don't work. Notably, I've tried to fetch the entity back from DB through its id, and then update it, and save, but this doesn't seem to commit.

Thanks much.

=============

Hello Nathan. Thanks. It doesn't update in the logs either. No UPDATE instruction just SELECT

here are the application.properties settings :

```
#==== connect to calanco ======#
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=xxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mapping=true

#temporary settings
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate=TRACE
```

=============

UPDATE : Happy New Year Ken Chan ;) I did try to fetch the entity back from DB, update it, and save, but it doesn't persist into DB.

Here's the code :

```
@Transactional
public void saveTemplatesFromDTOList(List<TemplateDTO> templateDTOList) {
    for (TemplateDTO templateDTO : templateDTOList) {
        Template templateFetchFromDB = templateRepo.getOne(templateDTO.getId());

        EntityToDTOConverter.fillTemplateEntityFromTemplateDTO(templateDTO, templateFetchFromDB); // does update the fields from DTO to entity fetched from DB

        templateRepo.save(templateFetchFromDB);

        em.persist(templateFetchFromDB); //doesn't work
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using any ORM tool like hibernate or not. If yes then, show the configuration file also.

Comment: Hello. I believe Spring Data "magic" does use Hibernate as a base. No special config just annotations (Spring Boot).

Comment: Hello Nathan. Thanks. It doesn't update in the logs either. No UPDATE instruction just SELECT

Comment: Why you do not use JpaRepository methodes ?

Comment: Back after some time. Thanks TinyOS. Using Spring Data Repository already. And method "save" does a "EntityManager.persist" in the background. Honestly, don't know what solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

`merge()` only works for the `@Entity` instance . It does not work on `DTO`.

The correct way is to use `entityManager` to get the entity which require update , then update its value by invoking its methods. When the transaction commits , the changes you made in the entity will be updated to database. Please note that you don't need to call `merge()` for the update which I notice many boys are doing wrong. `merge()` is for updating the detached entities back to the database which is another story.

So, the general flow for updating one DTO is something like below (Please modify it for the list version for exercise :D)

```
@Transactional
public void saveTemplatesFromDTO(TemplateDTO dto) {
    Template template = em.find(Template.class , dto.getTemplateId());

    //Get DTO value to update template
    template.setFoo(dto.getFoo());
    template.setBar(dto.getBar());
    //blablabla......

}
```

Comment: Happy New Year ;) I did try to fetch the entity back from DB, update it, and save, but it doesn't persist into DB.

Here's the code :

Comment: Happy New Year ~ Then most probably it is due to you do not configure transaction property.At least , you have to `@EnableTransactionManagement` in your spring boot configuration and define the `PlatformTransactionManager`......

Comment: Thanks Ken Chan for the time. Working now (edited the OQuestion). No need for configuring the transaction, it seems